# .xcworkspace doesn't have Archive option enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I have project for which I had no problems with archiving in Xcode. The "Archive" option worked just fine under the "Product" menu. 
But after I installed a framework with Cocoapods and started working with the .xcworkspace instead of the .xcodeproj , I noticed that the "Archive" option in grayed out in the .xcworkspace, but not in the .xcodeproj.
So any idea, why this is happening?

Here is a screenshot of the "Product Menu", it shows the Archive option grayed out

[image]
thanks

-Malena

Comment: Can you post any screenshots?

Comment: Just loaded a screenshot

Answer (score 3):

choose an ios device instead of the simulator then it will become available

Comment: how do you mark it as the answer, I don't see any options to do that

Answer (score 2):

Set build target to 'Generic iOS Device' instead of a simulator.